# ng-repeater issue Duplicates in a repeater is not allowed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a form like below, this using ng-repeat directive in  angular and it whenever I created a new row complains 
"Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed.".

[image]

While I understand the solution for this is by putting "track by $index", however it causes another issue, which clicking delete on one row deletes the value of other field. So I suspect that track by index is OK for static text but not input form. So how to use ng-repeat correctly for my case? See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rudygunawan/SX4gE/1/) for demo.

My current code :

**HTML**

```
<div class="row-fluid spacer10">
    <a ng-click="addAKA()" class="btn btn-primary spacer5 left30"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Add New Alias</a>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid spacer10"></div>
<div class="row-fluid spacer5" ng-repeat="item in aliasList track by $index">
    <input type="text" class="span6 left30" ng-model="item">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteAKA($index)">delete</button>
    <BR/>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.addAKA = function ()
{
    if($scope.aliasList == null)
    {
        $scope.aliasList = [];
    }
    $scope.aliasList.push("");
    $scope.aliasjson = JSON.stringify($scope.aliasList);
}


$scope.deleteAKA = function (idx)
{
    var aka_to_delete = $scope.aliasList[idx];
    $scope.aliasList.splice(idx, 1);
    $scope.aliasjson = JSON.stringify($scope.aliasList);
}
```

Comment: Can you check if $index is 0 based or 1 based. If $index is 1 based then you need to do `splice(idx-1,1);` It should work otherwise.

Comment: $index is always 0 based in angular. see my jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Just change the way you iterate. Instead of this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in aliasList track by $index">
```

do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in aliasList">
```

`$index` will be still available inside the element, use like this:

```
<button ng-click='deleteItem($index)'>Delete</button>
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6cDbM/4/) for a correct solution

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your approach.

Since you are directly binding a string to ng-model and ng-repeat creates a child scope, any change to the value would not reflect back. Change you scope model to something like

```
$scope.list = [{text:"one"},{text:"two"}];
```

and bind to `i.text` instead of binding to `i` as you did earlier.

The deleteItem method was called using item instead of index. See my fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/JS6aJ/1/